# Arrays for keeping track of letter grades

Tags: arrays

Need help writing a program. I can't figure out how to add to a certaint array. Below is the program I have to write. Any help would be appreciated.

Write an application that will use a one-dimensional array. Ask the user for a series of numeric grades (a grade of -1 will end the input). Create a one-dimensional array to keep track of grade ranges. For example:

Index 0 represents grades in the range of 90 - 100
Index 1 represents grades in the range of 80 - 89
Index 2 represents grades in the range of 70 - 79
Index 3 represents grades in the range of 60 - 69
Index 4 represents grades in the range of 59 or below

Display the number of A's, B's, C's, D's, and F's; also display the average, highest, and lowest grade.
Here is what your program should look like:

Enter a numeric grade (0-100) or -1 to quit: 90

Enter a numeric grade (0-100) or -1 to quit: 82

Enter a numeric grade (0-100) or -1 to quit: 96

Enter a numeric grade (0-100) or -1 to quit: -1

Number of A grades: 2

Number of B grades: 1

Number of C grades: 0

Number of D grades: 0

Number of F grades: 0

Average is: 89.33

Highest grade is: 96

Lowest grade is: 82

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a better way to do this, such as breaking the problem into separate methods and thus making your code much easier to debug/maintain, but here is the way I did it without using any methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int SIZE = 100;
    int[] array = new int[SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    int ans;
    int[] gradeRange = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    double total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int highest = array[0];




    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a numeric grade (0-100) or -1 to quit:");
    ans = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (ans != -1 && count < array.length) {
        array[count] = ans;
        count++;  //counter used to keep track of the array length

        if (ans >= 90) {
            gradeRange[0]++;

        }
        else if (ans >= 80) {
            gradeRange[1]++;

        }
        else if (ans >= 70) {
            gradeRange[2]++;

        }
        else if (ans >= 60) {
            gradeRange[3]++;

        }
        else if (ans < 60) {
            gradeRange[4]++;

        }

        System.out.println("Enter a numeric grade (0-100) or -1 to quit:");
        ans = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    int[] secarray = new int[count];   
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        secarray[index] = array[index];
    }
    int min = secarray[0];



    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        total += array[index];
        average = total / count;
    }


    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        if (array[index] > highest)
            highest = array[index];

    }
    for (int index = 1; index < secarray.length; index++) {

        if (secarray[index] < min)
            min = secarray[index];
    }







    System.out.println("Number of A grades: " + gradeRange[0]);
    System.out.println("Number of B grades: " + gradeRange[1]);
    System.out.println("Number of C grades: " + gradeRange[2]);
    System.out.println("Number of D grades: " + gradeRange[3]);
    System.out.println("Number of F grades: " + gradeRange[4]);

    System.out.printf("Average is: %.1f\n ", average);
    System.out.println("Lowest grade is: " + min);
    System.out.println("Highest grade is: " + highest); 


}//end main
```